# ZDCChat matches UIWebView even after upgrading pod for WKWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, wkwebview, itms-90809

I already upgraded UIWebView to WKWebView and even manually checked keyword `UIWebView` in my workspace and no more UIWebView.

Also updated pods.

But after hit command `grep -r UIWebView .` it always shows some pods are still matched UIWebView.

```
Sunils-MacBook-Pro:xxx-ios-app suniltarge$ grep -r UIWebView .
Binary file ./XXX.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/suniltarge.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate matches
Binary file ./Pods/ZDCChat/ZDCChatAPI.framework/ZDCChatAPI matches
Binary file ./Pods/ZDCChat/ZDCChat.framework/ZDCChat matches
Binary file ./Pods/.git/index matches
```

Does anyone also face the same problem?

> ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - Apple will no longer accept
> submissions of new apps that use UIWebView as of April 30, 2020 and
> app updates that use UIWebView as of December 2020. Instead, use
> WKWebView for improved security and reliability.

Comment: Which version of `ZDCChat` you are using?

Comment: `ZDCChat (1.4.1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://developer.zendesk.com/embeddables/docs/ios-chat-sdk/setup

> This is the developer guide for Chat SDK v1. The new Chat SDK v2 for iOS is now available and is the recommended version to integrate Chat into your mobile app. It also removes the dependency on UIWebView which has been deprecated by Apple.

I guess you need to upgrade to latest framework https://github.com/zendesk/chat_sdk_ios.